# Jquery select first and last divs from a list of items

Tags: jquery, html

how do I use jquery to select the first and last item divs in the following snippet and apply a different additional class to each:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

These will be somewhere on a web page. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you open a `<div>` but close an `</item>`. Probably a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't get much easier than:

```
$('.item:first').addClass('first');
$('.item:last').addClass('last');
```

You can also do it in a single command, if you want to save a few cycles:

```
$('.item')
    .eq(0).addClass('first').end()
    .eq(-1).addClass('last').end();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.item').filter(':first').addClass('first-class').end().filter(':last').addClass('last-class')
```

Try taking a look at [jQuery's Selector API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for other selectors.

Comment: It was a good idea to show `.filter(':first, :last')` - it is possible that's what the OP (original poster) needs. Depends on how you interpret "a different additional class to each"

Comment: FWIW, the page is large, and rounded borders are applied to those first and last divs: the user will see them become round once the page loads.

Comment: @Adrian33 - that's probably something you wanted so mention. You may also want to consider a CSS solution, it can work on all modern browsers, and will be visible from the start.